# c# datatable writexml control column names

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, converters

In my program I´m writing to XML content of table of SQLite DB. Everything is going fine but, output format is not suitable for me. How can I apply my own names in elements. Because if I load from SQLite to DataTable and trying to save through WriteXML Names of columns are in name of Elements. I wat to put names of Element as attribute of element. Please take a look, here is my code.

My C# code:

```
namespace SQLiteDemo
{
    internal class Program
    {   
        private const string DatabaseFile = "j.db";
        private const string DatabaseSource = "data source=" + DatabaseFile;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the file which will be hosting our database
            if (!File.Exists(DatabaseFile))
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(DatabaseFile);
            }

            // Connect to the database 
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseSource))
            {
                // Create a database command
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    // Select and display database entries
                    command.CommandText = "Select * FROM DB_company_5000";

                    var ds = new DataTable();

                    ds.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                    ds.WriteXml("jj.xml");

                    connection.Close(); // Close the connection to the database
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
<DB_company_5000>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Velin Ivan</Name>
    <Adress>VamberskĂˇ 273</Adress>
    <City>London 18</City>
    <TEL>NULL</TEL>
    <EXT>NULL</EXT>
</DB_company_5000>
```

Desired output:

```
    <table name="DB_company_5000">
        <column name="ID">1</column>
        <column name="Name">Velin Ivan</column>
        <column name="Adress">VamberskĂˇ 273</column>
        <column name="City">London 18</column>
        <column name="TEL">NULL</column>
        <column name="EXT">NULL</column>
    </table>
```

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since basic XML is just string data, we can solve this problem using simple string replacement. It isn't particularly elegant, but I think it answers the question:

```
string xml = @"<DB_company_5000>
                 <ID>3</ID>
                 <Name>Velin Ivan</Name>
                 <Adress>VamberskĂˇ 273</Adress>
                 <City>London 18</City>
                 <TEL>NULL</TEL>
                 <EXT>NULL</EXT>
               </DB_company_5000>";

xml = xml.Replace("<DB_company_5000>", "<table name=\"DB_company_5000\">");
xml = xml.Replace("</DB_company_5000>", "</table>");
xml = xml.Replace("<ID>", "<column name=\"ID\">");
xml = xml.Replace("</ID>", "</column>");
// ETC...
```

Comment: Yes, it is very simple but powerful. Thanks. I was looking for some way to use some build in mechanism to do it. Some thing like define my own specific data format in XML. Or use somehow columnmapping by attribute or mappingtype.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the question as answered (click the check mark icon). That's how it works around here.